# Calling appendGrid variable in a separate Javascript method

Tags: javascript, html

I hope this is just a simple question. So I'm declaring the appendGrid in a script tag in a HTML file. In a different location in the same HTML file, I have a saveTicket() method. When I call the appendGrid variable over here, I get the "variable not defined" error.

How can I get my appendGrid variable over to my saveTicket() method?
The saveTicket() method is called from a button click that is not related to appendGrid. But I need the appendGrid data in my saveTicket() method.

Pseudo Code HTML:

```
<script>
function saveTicket(){
//need to get var myAppendGrid data over here
}
</script>



<table id="tblAppendGrid" align="center">
</table>
<script>
$(function () {
var myAppendGrid = new AppendGrid({
initRows: 1,
element: "tblAppendGrid",
columns: [...]
});

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many way you can achieve this, but the easier in your case is to make `myAppendGrid` variable global by removing `var`

```
<script>
function saveTicket(){
//need to get var myAppendGrid data over here
}
</script>



<table id="tblAppendGrid" align="center">
</table>
<script>
$(function () {
myAppendGrid = new AppendGrid({
initRows: 1,
element: "tblAppendGrid",
columns: [...]
});

});

</script>
```

A better approach would be to put your `saveTicket()` function in the same scope where you defined `myAppendGrid` variable

```
var myAppendGrid = new AppendGrid({
  initRows: 1,
  element: "tblAppendGrid",
  columns: [...]
});

function saveTicket() {
  console.log(myAppendGrid);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I tried this and it works! However, is it a good practice to make it a global variable? Genuine question.

Comment: Not really, you are better to put your function in the same scope, see my edit

Comment: Start by reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. I can do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a "name space" in technical words it's just a global object. But with the "name space" you have more options to assign objects in objects and not just to overwrite one given global variable.

```js
var myNameSpace = {};

var myButton = document.querySelector('.my-super-awesome-button');
myButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var data = myNameSpace.myAppendGrid.getAllValue();
    console.log(data);
});

$(function(){
  myNameSpace.myAppendGrid = new AppendGrid({
    element: "tblAppendGrid",
    uiFramework: "bootstrap4",
    iconFramework: "fontawesome5",
    columns: [
      {
        name: "col-1",
        display: "Column 1"
      },
      {
        name: "col-2",
        display: "Column 2"
      },
      {
        name: "col-3",
        display: "Column 3"
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```css
.my-super-awesome-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.appendgrid@2/dist/AppendGrid.js"></script>

<div class="my-super-awesome-button">click me</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <table id="tblAppendGrid"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting approach. But over here, there would have to be a button click to even initialize the namespace right? Or would the namespace be initialized/used even without a button click?

Comment: @BloodRedDevil  it‘s initialized on page load and ready to be used